# Merge similar array keys

Tags: php, arrays

So I am searching a large body of text and extracting common phrases, then I end up with an array like this:

```
Array(
    [past due] => 21
    [past due notice] => 7
    [past due 60 day] => 17
    [60 day notice] => 32
)
```

The keys are the phrases and the values are the number of times that phrase appeared in the given text. In the example above, I would like to combine these keys and sum the values because they all mean the same thing, to me. So I would end up with an array like this:

```
Array(
    [past due] => 77
)
```

This is just an example, the keys, values, etc. will constantly be changing. I am just starting on this piece of the project so there is no code to post yet. I am just looking for ideas, direction, etc. so I don't have to reinvent the wheel if someone has done something similar or as an idea. As always, thanks in advance!

> **UPDATE:**
>
> With all of the contributions here and in reading other questions, I think I am going to try to group
> them using regex before I build the array.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: You will need to create an array map.

Comment: @PolishPrince - Noted. Sounds like I posted this to soon. Thanks for the input on using array_map().

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sum values of the array of the same key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-values-of-the-array-of-the-same-key)

Comment: @MichaelRushton - It is very similar. The main difference being my array keys are not identical, as they are in that question. It is however good reference so thank you!

Comment: Ah, sorry. Misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php):

```
$result = array('past_date' => array_sum($array));
```

Of course, this requires that you build the array first, grouping by a common meaning. PHP doesn't understand the semantics of language, obviously.

Comment: Ah, I like where this is going. Let me try it out...

Comment: Despite my update to the question, I am marking this as my answer since it got me the closest and your persistence to help me so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is very similar questions, where you can find your answer.

Check this:

[Merging arrays with the same keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881443/merging-arrays-with-the-same-keys)

[PHP - Merge duplicate array keys in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165406/php-merge-duplicate-array-keys-in-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll check them out.