# Merge Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a somewhat complicated function that builds an array structure dynamically to insert fields into MongoDB. We store the structure in MySQL.

The function outputs the following array structure:

```
Array
(
    [address] => Array
        (
            [street] => 10 Stack St
        )

)

Array
(
    [address] => Array
        (
            [city] => Overflow Mountains
        )

)
    Array
(
    [address] => Array
        (
            [state] => CM
        )

)
Array
(
    [address] => Array
        (
            [zip] => 01010
        )

)
```

I need to merge these arrays so it looks like

```
    [address] => Array
        (
            [street] => 10 Stack St
            [city] => Overflow Mountains
            [state] => CM
            [zip] => 01010
        )
```

How would I go about doing this? I am using PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Merge duplicate array keys in a multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165406/php-merge-duplicate-array-keys-in-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Those are 4 different arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_replace_recursive()`.

Let your arrays be `$array1, $array2,  $arrray3,  $array4`

You can try

```
array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array_merge($array1['address'], $array2['address'], $array3['address'], $array4['address']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_merge($a['address'], $b['address'], $c['address'], $d['address']);
```